# How To Repeatedly Delete Differently Named Items

Tags: python, tkinter

Recently I was working on a program where when one clicked a button, it would delete all of the tkinter buttons they made through a .yml file. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
(All TKinter Root Init Here)

button1 = Button(root, text="hi")
button2 = Button(root, text="hi again")
button3 = Button(root, text="hi again again")
button4 = Button(root, text="OK this is getting tiring")
button5 = Button(root, text="go away")
button6 = Button(root, text="...")

def del_all():
    for i in range(999999999):
        button(i).place_forget() #I was hoping to make button(i) give the output button1, then button2, and so on.
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Without seeing how the buttons are named, it's hard to say, please include more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `nametowidget` in tkinter,example like:

```
import tkinter as tk

r = tk.Tk()

for i in range(5):
    tk.Button(r,text=i).pack()

r.nametowidget(".!button").pack_forget()
r.mainloop()
```

This will remove the first button.If you want to remove the second button, you need to use `r.nametowidget(".!button2").pack_forget()`

So for you code,you may need to use:

```
def del_all():
    root.nametowidget(".!button").place_forget()
    for i in range(2, 999999999):
        root.nametowidget(".!button"+str(i)).place_forget()
```

About the parameter in the `nametowidget`, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106778/how-to-get-a-widget-name-with-tkinters-nametowidget-function-within-a-class) is a clear description.

---

You could also use `winfo_children` and use `.widgetName` to check whether it is a button,like:

```
import tkinter as tk

r = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(r, text="test").pack()

for i in range(5):
    tk.Button(r,text=i).pack()

for i in r.winfo_children():
    if i.widgetName == 'button':
        i.pack_forget()

r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would depend on how the buttons are named/stored.

For example, if the buttons were a list. Something like:

```
buttons = ['button1', 'button2', 'button3', 'button4']
```

Then you an delete by calling:

```
buttons.remove()
```

And that would 'clear' the list.

Comment: I dont think you understood what I was saying.

My goal is not to delete items from a list, it's to delete tkinter button widgets.

Comment: It's the same idea. You could put the tkinter button widgets in a list and remove the list.

Comment: The thing is, I am a beginner, so I dont **know** how to do this.